# covert hashmap to json data in java

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jackson

I have 2 hashmap which I want to store in DB. For that I am converting them in json and for my first hashmap it is working fine but 2nd hashmap contains an object of a class. So it is giving me error while inserting that hashmap in DB. Here is my code

```
public void insertInput(HashMap Hash,AnalysisResponse analysisResponseModelObj) {
        BaseDAO baseDaoObj = null;
        JSONObject json = null;
        JSONObject jsonData = null;
        HashMap userInput = null;
        String transactionid=null;
        HashMap configmap=null;
        try {
jsonData=new HashMap();
            baseDaoObj = new BaseDAO();
            userInput = new HashMap();
            userInput = (HashMap) Hash
                    .get("userInputHashKey");
            json = new JSONObject();
            json.putAll(userInput);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            jsonData.putAll(Hash);

            String query = QueryUtilities.insertInputIntoTranactionLOg(json,jsonData,transactionid);
            int rowaffacted = baseDaoObj.executeUpdateQuery(query, null);
            System.out.println(rowaffacted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while fetching input ");
        }
    }
```

This is my update statemnet

```
 UPDATE logtable set input1 = '{"TYPE":"os","NAME":"linuxtest.abc.com"}',input2 = '{"isCategorySpecific":true,"dataFilterHashMap":{"arg_infilename":[com.abc.pqr.WhereClauseGenerator@13ff97c],"TYPE":"os","CI_NAME":"ten","METRIC_TYPE":"cpu"},"typeOfLanguage":"java"}'WHERE id ='1'
```

Here input2 contains 1 object of class so it's giving error.

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "com" is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply covert using `JSONObject jsonWithMap = new JSONObject(map);` and try to insert.

Comment: I tried that but giving error ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "com" is invalid.
  Position: 105

Comment: @SonalRuhatiya so you are getting it for your custom class. right? if yes, is it serialized class and try to overridde toString() method and implement it for your required output.

Comment: still not working. i even tried using jackson-ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); but the problem is the objectmapper doesnot have any method to write in hashmap format

Comment: @SonalRuhatiya it has, to convert to json string, ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(map)

Comment: @SonalRuhatiya. any luck? have you tried to override toString?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use prepared statement to avoid conflicts with sql syntax, try something like [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/sample-jdbc-preparedstatement-sql-update):

```
// create our java preparedstatement using a sql update query
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
  "UPDATE logtable SET input1 = ?, input2 = ? WHERE id = ?");

// set the preparedstatement parameters
ps.setString(1,json);
ps.setString(2,jsonData);
ps.setInt(3,transactionid);

// call executeUpdate to execute our sql update statement
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

it's not exactly PostgreSQL, but I think it should work as well. Btw. you always want to use Prepared-Statements, since you want to avoid [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)